# Deserialize a list from application.yml to @Value in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an old Spring MVC project (not Spring Boot, otherwise it would be easy) with the next configuration in application.yml

```yaml
spring-caching:
  enabled: true
  default-ttl: PT10M
  caches:
    - name: cache1
      ttl: PT10M
    - name: cache2
      ttl: PT10M
```

How can I deserialize this configuration to a variable with `@Value`? I've tried something like below but no success.

```java
@Value("${spring-caching.caches}")
private String props;

@Value("${spring-caching.caches}")
private List<MyClassNameTtl> props;

@Value("${spring-caching.caches}")
private List<Object> props;
```

Comment: I think it is not possible, because `@Value` binds (in contrast to @ConfigurationProperty) a **single** value, but you have multiple values. So you need to parse the yaml file at your own.